# Add listener to all cell in column table editable mode of Vaadin

Tags: listener, vaadin

I want add listener to change "." to "," in one column table of vaadin, in editable mode.
I create the table data with BeanItemContainer.

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a custom TableFieldFactory to then add the listener to each field that needs it.

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html

```
table.setTableFieldFactory(new MyTableFieldFactory());

...

public class MyTableFieldFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory {

    @Override
    public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
            Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
        String prop = (String) propertyId;
        if ("a".equals(prop)) { // propertyId of the column you wish to change
            AbstractField f = (AbstractField) super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext); // casting to AbstractField to set the field to immediate mode
            f.setImmediate(true);
            f.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                    String val = (String) event.getProperty().getValue();
                    val = val.replace(".", ",");
                    event.getProperty().setValue(val);
                }
            });
            return f;
        }
        return super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code work ok, but Vaadin change before your code replace the value... and show this. Value entry = 1124.14 and Vaadin pint 112,414 . Your code is good,but Vaadin joke me.